# Show iPad SwiftUI sidebar programmatically based on binding/state

Tags: swift, ipad, swiftui

I've seen the other answers on this. Seems like there's no good solution. Just in case, thought I'd ask if there have been any changes that allow you to display the sidebar by default or based on a `Bool`.

If I have a `NavigationView` like this containing two views, I'd like the the sidebar to show if the user isn't logged in:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isActive = true
    @State var genActive = false
    @State var loggedIn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            LogoView()
            GenericDataView(loggedIn: $loggedIn)
        }
    }
}
```

The sidebar brings up the login screen. Ultimately, I'd like the sidebar to show with the user's main screen blurred out behind it. Image below. Just putting together the basic login now as a base for the app, so don't need to work in the complexity of `NavigationLink`, etc.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It seems like `NavigationSplitView` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview/) with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitviewvisibility may solve this

Comment: Yes, plan to explore iOS 16 stuff and update, but for now can't use the beta stuff.

Comment: When you asked if there had been any changes, I assumed that would mean updates in the new version.

Comment: Sorry. Most of the answers are a few months old. Just thought maybe someone came up with a more elegant solution in the meantime.

Comment: @Ja5onHoffman Have you found a solution for this? I'm using `NavigationSplitView` on iOS 16 and the issue is still there: Setting `NavigationSplitViewVisibility`to `.double` or `.all`works when the sidebar is displayed side-by-side to the content, but not when the sidebar overlays the content (like in your example screenshot).